# How to make emacs auto-name buffer based on filename?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I often load many 00readme.txt files into emacs, and the default 
buffer name "00readme.txt" isn't very helpful.

I use rename-buffer manually to rename them "project1", "project2", etc.

How do I tell emacs: "when loading /foo/bar/00readme.txt, 
automatically name the buffer project1, not 00readme.txt"?

Comment: The information you've given makes the renaming seem random.  Is there any correlation between the filename you're loading and the buffer name you want?

Answer (score 8):

You might also want to look at the [uniquify](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Uniquify.html) library shipped with emacs, which can add parts of the directory name to the buffer name, when opening files with the same name.

Comment: is there a way to always use uniquify, even when there isn't a duplicate name?

Answer (score 1):

```
;; toss this into your .emacs file and fiddle with it till you get what you want
(defun my-buffer-renamer() 
(interactive) 
(let ()  ; <--  local vars in here

  (message "bufer name is %s" (current-buffer))
  (rename-buffer "something else") ; make sure to make unique names

))

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'my-buffer-renamer) ; only do this once
```

Emacs supports a plethora of 'hook' functions,  callbacks that get executed when a particular action occurs.  Here, we add a function to gets invoked when a text file get's loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice configuration for `uniquify`, which is the standard Emacs way to solve your problem:

```
(require 'uniquify)
(setq uniquify-buffer-name-style 'reverse)
      uniquify-separator " • "
      uniquify-after-kill-buffer-p t
      uniquify-ignore-buffers-re "^\\*"
```